Configuration of the Salesforce CLI connected app
Do we know the exact configuration of the Salesforce CLI connected app?
While developing and testing my own connected app, I saw the Salesforce CLI listed along with my own connected app in Connections, that got me wondering about the configuration of the salesforce CLI connected app

what part of configuration you are interested in?

The Salesforce CLI connected app is auto-configured by Salesforce to handle communication with your org. You don’t need to change anything, but you can view it in Setup > App Manager if you're curious. Best to leave it as is!
